# State Variable assigned to props data model undefined inside setState React

Tags: reactjs

I have passed a data model as props from Parent Component (`MinorStructures`) to Child component (`PhotoGallery`).
The parent Component looks like the following:

```
export default class MinorStructures extends Component {

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        // This is a super data model class, its main function is to collect 
          //    data from all the children components.
        this.state = {
            MinorStructures: {
                 layer: 3,
                 layerName: 'MinorStructures',
                 layerId: -1,
                 agencyId: -1, //to be determined later
                 galleryModel:{
                    selectedFile: null
                 }
                   
            }
        };
        

        this.panes = [
            {
                menuItem: 'Photo Gallery', render: () =>
                    <Tab.Pane>
                        <PhotoGallery triggerNeedSave={this.props.triggerNeedSave}
                            disabled={this.props.disabled}
                            loggedIn = {this.props.loggedin}
                            minorModel={this.state.MinorStructures}/>
                    </Tab.Pane>
            },
        ];
    }   
}
```

I have removed few codes from the parent class which is not necessary for this problem.

The Child Component is like the following:

```
export default class PhotoGallery extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const {minorModel} = this.props
    this.state={
         cameraOpen: false,
         photoModel: minorModel.galleryModel
     }
     console.log("Constructor State ", this.state)
   }
   handleChange = e =>{
     this.props.triggerNeedSave();
     this.setState({[photoModel.selectedFile]:e.target.files[0]})
     console.log(this.state)
   }
   render() {
     const uploadClick = e => {
         hiddenFileInput.current.click();
     };
     return (
        <div>
           {!this.state.cameraOpen && <Button size='tiny' onClick={uploadClick} 
                 color='brown'  
                 disabled ={this.props.disabled}>Upload Photos from Device</Button>}
           <input id="photo" name="selectedFile" type="file"
               onChange={this.handleChange} 
                 ref={hiddenFileInput} style={{display:'none'}} />
    <Button size='tiny' onClick={checkModel} color='brown'
        disabled ={this.props.disabled}>
          Click To Check
    </Button>
                    
     </div>
   );
};
return (
    <div id="root">
         <Gallery />
     </div>   
   )}  
}
```

In the `state` of `PhotoGallery` class I have a `photoModel` that takes the data model from `MinorStructures` as props. When I select a picture and do `setState` in the `handleChange` method of `PhotoGallery` class it says `photoModel` is not defined. But I have defined that variable in the state which stores data model passed as props from `MinorStructures`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set a `name` attribute for the `file type input html tag` and then used the below code to set the value

```
this.setState({ [name]: e.target.files[0] });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using dynamic keys when changing state with [] to access properties on this.state

```
this.setState({[photoModel.selectedFile]:e.target.files[0]})
```

The correct way would be to change state with

```
this.setState({photoModel.selectedFile:e.target.files[0]})
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Because inside setState the key name for each of them has to be a single valued. Whenever I remove the [] wrapped around `photoModel.selectedFile` it will throw error.